# How to apply a function that involves two variables in python - positional arguments issue

Tags: python, function, apply

I am trying to define a variable `--yieldgift--` using values from two other variables `-- yieldposter` and `yieldgiftbox`. I have used conditional language in order to do so (see code below). Now, I am trying to apply the function to the newly named `--fieldgift--` variable, but I get the following error: `('yieldgift() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given', 'occurred at index yieldposter')`

My dataframe is named --deposit--. Here is what I did to define the variable --yieldgift-- followed by my attempt to apply the function.

```py
def yieldgift():
    if deposit.yieldposter == 'Y' and deposit.yieldgiftbox == 'Y':
        return 'both'
    elif deposit.yieldposter == 'Y':
        return 'poster'
    elif deposit.yieldgiftbox == 'Y':
        return 'box'

deposit['yieldgift'] = deposit[['yieldposter', 'yieldgiftbox']].apply(yieldgift)
```

I get the following error:

````
('yieldgift() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given', 'occurred at index yieldposter')```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed to `apply` needs to take an argument: the row or column you want it to be applied to.

Comment: I am trying to apply the function to a new column, yieldgift using the values from yieldposter and yieldgiftbox. Is this what is reflected above?

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately what I used, which worked:

```
deposit['yieldgift'] = deposit.apply(lambda x: yieldgift(x['yieldposter'], x['yieldgiftbox']), axis=1)
```